# Enable disable fixed column in DataTable using a button

Tags: jquery, datatable, toggle, fixed

Myself created a html table with fixed columns using jquery DataTable with reference to [This example](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/bootstrap.html) as,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false
    } );
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table, {
        leftColumns: 2
    } );
} );
```

**UPDATE:** Myself trying to enable/disable the fixed column using a button as given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqsadgez/) as,

```
var columnNumber = 2;
  $('#ToggleColumns').click(function () { 
  if(columnNumber == 2)
  {
columnNumber = 0;  
  }
  else {
  columnNumber = 2; 
  }
foo();
```

where the `foo()` contains the columnNumber to be fixed. What is the correct syntax to toggle the column number based on the button?

Comment: enable or disable in what context.. they should not behave as a fixed column after disabling and vice verca ?

Comment: Myself want to enable fixed column feature in some cases. In other conditions it should be disabled using a button click. Again, it should be enabled if the user click the button again and vice versa.

Comment: Please see my answer below @AnkushJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved by using `table.destroy();` method of datatable and initializing new options with new columnNumber.

Sample Link: http://jsfiddle.net/eqsadgez/1/

Please suggest if any better ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you can do is add or remove "sorting" class on each click

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked.

```
$(".DTFC_Cloned").addClass('d-none');
```

**.DTFC_Cloned** is a class datatables gives to a cloned table with fixed column data.